# System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to <localpath>: exit code: -1

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to run docker Desktop in my windows 10 Local. have installed it successfully but while running it I am getting the below error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to <localpath>: exit code: -1
 stdout: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

I think it is saying some windows services need to be enabled, but I don't know which service has to be enabled could someone please help me with this concern?

```
docker version 
C:\Users\lenova>docker --version
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have same issue, in my case it was a conflict with laravel Valet. So i just run `valet stop` and restart docker. You can find various solution here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8204

Comment: do i need to run this in command prompt?

Comment: Do you have valet installed in your machine ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Uninstall Docker.
- Uncheck Containers, Hyper-V, Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows features
- Restart the system
- Install Docker Desktop
- Restart System
- Start Docker Desktop

Comment: Worked for me but had to install Docker Desktop AS ADMIN and Start Docker Desktop AS ADMIN

Answer (score 13):

Right click on docker icon, run as administrator (if you have administrator rights on your computer). It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

Try delete `%USERPROFILE%/.wslconfig`. If it helps then you can try to modify it so that it work. As for me I deleted the file, because on my workstation docker didn't want to work with it

Answer (score 5):

Almost sure, that the accepted answer will work. However, it won't be an option, if you utilize WSL for other purposes as well. In that case, you may have several configurations/apps in WSL and just reinstalling or deleting your configuration will probably be a bad solution.

Furthermore: **WSL is not the issue for this error!** It is created by **Docker engine configuration** which will **kill the WSL service** (`LxxsManager`). This may happen because of

- changed configuration (by you) or
- because of a Docker update, maybe also
- because of Windows updates

You can find a detailed discussion about this issue on Docker's [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8204).

I personally experienced this problem after installing **updates on Windows** while running **Docker v3.5.2**. And again, reinstalling/killing WSL is not an option for me! So I tried to kill all services (Docker and WSL) and update Docker. Unfortunately that did not work in first place, since `LxxsManager` was in some weird state and I could not even kill it any more (even a kill command as admin with force switch did not do it's job!)... So here is my solution to fix that problem:

1. Remove Docker from autostart
2. Restart Windows (**Yippiee**: WSL works again! )
3. Install a new version of Docker (in my case v.4.2.0)
4. Restart Windows again (probably not necessary, but for me it was because Docker engine did not start before a Windows restart)
5. Start Docker (**Yippiee**: Docker works again! ☺️)

**Note**: Since I did not change Docker configuration, I installed an update. If you changed configuration options resulting in that crash, your solution may be different. Literally, instead of updating Docker (step 3) you would probably roll back your Docker configuration changes instead.

Answer (score 1):

run as administrator , and you switch the container to windows by clicking the icon bar in the right corner taskbar and choose switch to windows container

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux

Answer (score 1):

I had to exit Private Internet Access (PIA) VPN to get docker to work on my system. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I had the PgAdmin 4 app running, and when I closed it and tried starting Docker Desktop again it booted normally.

Not sure if there is a link, but an easy solution to try.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/547#issuecomment-873540236

- Copy below snippet:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\AppId_Catalog\0408F7A3]
"AppFullPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"
"PermittedLspCategories"=dword:80000000
```

- Save it as a file wsl.reg
- Execute the file to update the registry
- Launch Ubuntu again
- Issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

Restarting wsl worked for me.

Run the following

- `wsl --shutdown`, wait for it to shutdown
- `wsl`, wait for it to start

Start Docker Desktop after this.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of Docker for Windows is very bad. I catch these dangerous very often.

[image]

Check list:

(1) Use this tool https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html . Search `docker`, delete all. [image]

(2) Remove WSL sub system, Hyper-V, then restart

[image]

(3). Create file `foo.reg` has content

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\AppId_Catalog\0408F7A3]
"AppFullPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"
"PermittedLspCategories"=dword:80000000
```

run.

(4) Uninstall Docker

(5) Run cmd type `...` . Delete folder `.docker`

[image]

[image]
Delete Docker folder in `Program Files`

[image]

(6) delete

[image]

(7) Install latest version of Docker.

(8) Re-install feature WSL for Windows.

[image]

Install Ubuntu from Windows store

[image]

(9) Re-install Docker (as Administrator)

(10) Run Docker as Administrator .

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to C:\Users%Your_USER-NAME%\AppData\Roaming\Docker
2. Delete settings.json
3. Start the docker

This helped me with a lot of other docker errors after update of windows/changes in windows etc...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting a similar error. This was happening because Docker desktop didn't have permissions to access the path `C:\Users\Adithya\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro`. This started happening after I switched to WSL2 backend.

The solution was to kill all docker process. Next, `Run Docker Desktop as Administrator`.

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\Adithya\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: 
exit code: -1 stdout: The operation timed out because a response was not received from the virtual machine or container.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run Linux and Windows containers side-by-side, an option is to turn off the WSL and use Hyper-v instead. This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was caused by **Acrylic DNS server**. Anything that holds **port 53**, would be a problem.

Interesting that it all worked fine for a few days after installation, maybe because I did not reboot the laptop all that time, only used the deep hibernation. So it was hard to guess what could break the docker setup, I was sure that it was because of the recently installed windows or docker updates.

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows 10:**

1. Open Services

[image]

2. Right click on LXSSMANAGER -> **Restart**

[image]

3. Close wsl using cmd with following command:

   ```
    wsl --shutdown
   ```
4. Execute following start wsl again:

   ```
    wsl
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved by the following steps:**

- Uninstall Docker and WSL 2 kernel.
- Uncheck Containers, Hyper-V, Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows
  features
- Restart the system
- Install Docker Desktop
- Restart System
- Start Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in WSL as it becomes unresponsive and returns a service error if you try the following command in PowerShell:

```
wsl -l -v
```

I believe the process can be simplified a bit more with:

- Uncheck Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows Features
- Reboot
- Turn the feature back on
- Re-apply the WSL2 update
- Reboot
- No need to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop.

This got me back up and running with Windows 10 Home (which requires WSL2) and Docker Desktop 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I did have issues with wsl not responding in Windows 10.

1. Kill docker-desktop processes.
2. Run powershell as administrator to restart wsl service.

`Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service
WARNING: Waiting for service 'LxssManager (LxssManager)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'LxssManager (LxssManager)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'LxssManager (LxssManager)' to stop...
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

3. Restart docker desktop.