# Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop with exit code -1 on win10 20H2 with docker desktop v3.2.2.61853

Tags: docker

I have installed latest docker desktop version 3.2.2.61853 on my thinkpad P50 workstation according to the official installation guide(OS win10 20H2 internal version 19042.870).When I start docker engine, it's pop up with following error:
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\snelgar\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1
stdout: ��: 0x80041002

stderr:
在 Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:行号 146
在 Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.d__17.MoveNext() 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:行号 169
--- 引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾 ---
在 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
在 Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.d__8.MoveNext() 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:行号 78
--- 引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾 ---
在 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
在 Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.d__26.MoveNext() 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:行号 104
--- 引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾 ---
在 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
在 Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.d__0.MoveNext() 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:行号 29
--- 引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾 ---
在 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
在 Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext() 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:行号 67
--- 引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾 ---
在 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
在 Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext() 位置 C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:行号 92

I have read other user's post [System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\lenova\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66074090/system-invalidoperationexception-failed-to-deploy-distro-docker-desktop-to-c-u), and tried the answer's solution, but it does not work. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.