# Docker desktop System.InvalidOperationException Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop

Tags: docker

Docker was working fine until later last week, then I began getting this error popping up.

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\SLynch24\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1
 stdout: {Application Error}

The exception s (0x
 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<DeployDistroAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 168
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 77
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 190
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__21.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 99"
```

I followed [this users thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66074090/system-invalidoperationexception-failed-to-deploy-distro-docker-desktop-to-c-u) but still have the same issue.

Comment: Does it literally print out `enter image description here`?  Can you edit the question to include the text of the error message, and the source code that produces it?

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize WSL for other purposes as well. In that case, you may have several configurations/apps in WSL and just reinstalling or deleting your configuration will probably be a bad solution.

Furthermore: WSL is not the issue for this error! It is created by Docker engine configuration which will kill the WSL service (`LxxsManager`). This may happen because of

changed configuration (by you) or
because of a Docker update, maybe also
because of Windows updates
You can find a detailed discussion about this issue on Docker's GitHub Issues.

I experienced this problem after installing updates on Windows while running **Docker v3.5.2**. And again, reinstalling/killing WSL is not an option for me! So I tried to kill all services (Docker and WSL) and update Docker. Unfortunately, that did not work in the first place, since `LxxsManager` was in some weird state and I could not even kill it anymore (even a kill command as admin with force switch did not do its job!)... So here is my solution to fix that problem:

1. Remove Docker from autostart
2. Restart Windows
3. Install a new version of Docker (in my case **v.4.2.0**)
4. Restart Windows again (probably not necessary, but for me, it was because the Docker engine did not start before a Windows restart)
5. Start Docker

Note: Since I did not change the Docker configuration, I installed an update. If you changed configuration options resulting in that crash, your solution may be different. Literally, instead of updating Docker (step 3), you would probably roll back your Docker configuration changes instead.

Comment: what do you mean by 'List item'?

Comment: There were some type @klutt.

Comment: @Swapnil I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this service is enable LxssManager. If not, try this command:

1. List item open cmd in administrator

```
sc config LxssManager start=auto
```